# Some questions about how implement a Swing Listener

Tags: java, swing

I have some doubts related this configuration of an **ActionListener** into a simple Java Swing example application.

Generally I always declared the listener as a **private inner class** that **implements ActionListener interface** but this example (found on the web) work in a different way:

```
package com.andrea.second;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


/* SimpleMeni it is a JFrame: a container */
public class SimpleMenu extends JFrame {

    public SimpleMenu() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();          // The menu bar containing the main menu voices

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));     

        // Creo 2 menu a tendina:
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File"); 
        JMenu bla = new JMenu("Bla");

        // Lega l'attivazione del menu allo shortcut ALT+F sulla tastiera:
        file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

        JMenuItem eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit", icon);      // Etichetta Exit con icona 
        eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        // Setta un messaggio testuale tooltip al passaggio del mouse sulla voce di menu:
        eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Exit application");   

        // Setto un listener con relativa azione definita dal metodo actionPerformed() della classe che implementa ActionListener:
        eMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        file.add(eMenuItem);


        menubar.add(file);
        menubar.add(bla);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        setTitle("Simple menu");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SimpleMenu ex = new SimpleMenu();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see this example don't declare the listener by a private inner class implementing ActionListener interface but do something like it:

```
    eMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

Where **eMenuItem** is the item on which I want handle the click event.

What exactly means this code:

```
(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

I think that it is creating a class that is ActionListener (that implement ActionListener interface) and at the same time he implement it (implementing the actionPerformed() method)

But I am not sure because I don't know this programming style.

Is it my reasoning correct? Can you give me more precise information about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you cite is creating an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

It is very similar to the inner classes you've been using, it just doesn't have a defined name. That means it can't be re-instantiated/reused elsewhere, but since its job is to just handle one type of event that isn't really an issue.

Comment: mmm maybe I am missing something...it CAN'T be re-instantiated/reused elsewhere, is it right?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Sorry, typo on my part. Fixed now.